# If x is congruent to -1 mod p , then how do we prove that x is congruent to $p$-$1$ mod $p$

Tags: number-theory, congruences

If x is congruent to -1 mod p , then how do we prove that x is congruent to $p$-$1$ mod   $p$ 
.
What i did as per definition of congruence $x$+$1$=$p$*$r$ as according to congruence definition x is congruent to   $a$ mod $b$ ,if $x$-$a$ is divisible by $b$ .

Comment: This is because $p\equiv 0\mod p$ so $p-1\equiv -1\mod p$. Congruence is compatible with addition.

Comment: Your assumption, $x\equiv -1 \pmod p$ means that we can find an integer $n$ with $x+1=pn$  it follows that $x+1-p=p(n-1)$.

Comment: @lulu can you write full statements and prove it, it will be helpful to me

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for.  Saying $a\equiv b\pmod p$ means that $a-b=pn$ for some integer  $n$.  I mean, that's the definition.  What part of what I wrote is not clear?

Comment: oh yes it is clear to me now ,x-(p-1)=p*something thus x is congruent to p-1 mod p

Answer (score 1):

Just use the definition, $a \equiv b \pmod m \iff m|a-b.$

So, $x \equiv -1 \pmod p \iff p|(x+1)\implies x+1=pk\space (k \in \Bbb Z$)

$\therefore x+1-p= pk-p=p(k-1)$, which is clearly a multiple of $p$.

So, we get that $p|(x+1-p) \implies p|\{x-(p-1)\} \iff x \equiv p-1 \pmod p $.